# MongoDB - file size is huge and growing

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that use mongo for storing short living data. All data older than 45 minutes is removed by script something like:

```
oldSearches = [list of old searches]
connection = Connection()
db = connection.searchDB
res = db.results.remove{'search_id':{"$in":oldSearches}})
```

I've checked current status -

```
>db.results.stats()
{
        "ns" : "searchDB.results",
        "count" : 2865,
        "size" : 1003859656,
        "storageSize" : 29315124464,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So, according to this 1gb of data occupies 29GB of storage. Data folder looks like this(You may see that many files are very old - last accessed in the middle of may):

```
ls -l /var/lib/mongodb/
total 31506556
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb nogroup          6 2011-06-05 18:28 mongod.lock
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup   67108864 2011-05-13 17:45 searchDB.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  134217728 2011-05-13 14:45 searchDB.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-20 20:45 searchDB.10
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-28 00:00 searchDB.11
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-27 13:45 searchDB.12
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-29 16:45 searchDB.13
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-06-07 13:50 searchDB.14
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-06-06 01:45 searchDB.15
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-06-07 13:50 searchDB.16
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-06-07 13:50 searchDB.17
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-06-06 09:07 searchDB.18
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  268435456 2011-05-13 14:45 searchDB.2
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  536870912 2011-05-11 00:45 searchDB.3
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 1073741824 2011-05-29 23:37 searchDB.4
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-13 17:45 searchDB.5
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-18 17:45 searchDB.6
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-16 01:45 searchDB.7
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-17 13:45 searchDB.8
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2146435072 2011-05-23 16:45 searchDB.9
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup   16777216 2011-06-07 13:50 searchDB.ns
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup   67108864 2011-04-23 18:51 test.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup   16777216 2011-04-23 18:51 test.ns
```

According to "top" mongod uses 29G of virtual memory ( and 780Mb of RSS)

Why do i have such abnormal values? Do i need to run something additional to  .remove() function to clean up database from old values?

Comment: Out of interest, have you investigated using Capped Collections for this kind of problem? This would remove the problems of disk space, remove the need for a removal script and may make the app faster...

Comment: As a sidenote: For such short-lived data I would use Redis which supports expire-timeout on any data.

Comment: Mongo is just plain storage heavy.  BSON takes up a lot of space because it stores the full key name as well as the value for each field in a document.  As others have said, there are workarounds, but you will need to accept large file system use if you use MongoDB.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> **Virtual memory size** and resident size will appear to be very large for the mongod process.  This is benign: virtual memory space will be just larger than the size of the datafiles open and mapped; resident size will vary depending on the amount of memory not used by other processes on the machine.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching

When you remove an object from MongoDB collection, the space it occupied is not automatically garbage collected and new records are only appended to the end of data files, making them grow bigger and bigger. This explains it all:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

For starters, simply use:

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

Comment: as far as i read - repair will totally block mongodb for a while - right? Do u have any expectations - how long will it take?

Comment: @Andrew: You can copy database files and run `db.repairDatabase()` at none production server in order to see how much it will take.

Comment: I know this ticket is old, but looks like Mongo behaviour has not changed since then; is there really no better way to clean up space, other then locking your entire production instance? is it just me that finds this annoying?

Comment: @JMac no, I find it to be extremely annoying as well. I inherited MongoDB from a "legacy" app and I can't wait to get rid of it. This thing is responsible for over 90% of all our issues/bug reports.

Comment: I know this is a terribly old thread but I just wanted point out the option of adding a member to a replica set.  Doing this automatically compresses the data for the new member.  Once added, start the new member as primary and delete everything on the previous primary and re-add it to the set.  While this may take time for large datasets, it will not block your database.

Comment: What do you recommend for  "non starters"