# Windows - I don't use MongoDb but it uses 3gb on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, diskspace

I installed mongodb to play around with it using [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org). I played around with it in that I created a simple db and stored some values from the command line and went on my way.  Six months later I'm looking at it and it's taking up 3 gigabytes of data and I haven't used it directly at all!

The only thing I can possibly think of that is using it is ruby or node, but both of these I use only as utilities and to play around with - I don't actually develop in them day to day and I don't run sites out of them.

I tried `db.repairDatabase()` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263729/mongodb-file-size-is-huge-and-growing) but to no avail. If anything it actually grew a bit.

What could be going on!?

Comment: Pre-allocation of files: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation and journal

Comment: Ah thanks @Sammaye - that's it. There is a note in there about how to disable pre-allocation but it seems to be aimed at starting mongo manually whereas its started automatically for me as a service. In addition, disabling is not the same as cleaning up. I'd like to actually reclaim the bulk of that disk space. Know how to do that?

Comment: You would have to erase the data already there and then modify your service handler for Mongod to use `--smallfiles` and `--nojournal` I believe. There might be a better way but thats the way I know of :(

Comment: @Sammaye you should move your comment to an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: It seems that would be a good idea, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to pre-allocation of files: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size whereby it will actually allocate a journal (5th of disk space or 3GB, whichever comes first) and other standard files.

Unfortunately MongoDB cannot switch this on and off within its own runtime currently. The best way is to amend the service handler to actually have the `--smallfiles` and `--nojournal` option added.