# Disk quota exceeded on OpenShift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I just deployed application to OpenShift, and it worked fine, until I ment to push changes. Then it started to warn me about disk quota exceeded, and I'm not able to do anything anymore.

Running `rhc app-tidy [app-name]` from terminal gave me this:

```
Warning: Gear 5395736e5004467cae0004ba is using 100.0% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/5395736e5004467cae0004ba/nodejs
```

`app-root/logs` folder is empty.

Running `du -h * | sort -rh | head -50`, gives me this:

```
481M    mongodb/data
481M    mongodb
385M    mongodb/data/journal
275M    app-root/runtime
275M    app-root
267M    app-deployments/2014-06-09_04-51-12.537
267M    app-deployments
157M    app-root/runtime/repo
156M    app-deployments/2014-06-09_04-51-12.537/repo
125M    app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules
125M    app-deployments/2014-06-09_04-51-12.537/repo/node_modules
119M    app-root/runtime/dependencies/.npm
119M    app-root/runtime/dependencies
111M    app-deployments/2014-06-09_04-51-12.537/dependencies/.npm
111M    app-deployments/2014-06-09_04-51-12.537/dependencies
```

Not sure why mongodb/data is taking so much space and what exactly is there? My database should be empty.

**** update ****

After running on my mongodb/data folder, here's what I got:

```
total 97M
drwxr-xr-x.  3 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 4.0K Jun  9 05:21 .
drwxr-xr-x. 11 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 4.0K Jun  9 04:44 ..
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 04:45 admin.0
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 04:45 admin.ns
drwxr-xr-x.  2 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 4.0K Jun  9 06:51 journal
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 06:51 local.0
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 06:51 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba    0 Jun  9 06:51 mongod.lock
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 04:45 surge.0
-rw-------.  1 5395736e5004467cae0004ba 5395736e5004467cae0004ba  16M Jun  9 04:45 surge.ns
```

Comment: mongodb/data is probably your `dbpath` folder - folder where mongo is storing it's database files. Post a `ls -lah` of that folder.

Comment: hey, @ChristianP, I just updated answer.

Answer (score 14):

Something that also helped me was to disable [journaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/)

Laying out complete steps

1. SSH into your OpenShift

   ```
   rhc ssh $@ -a $app
   ```
2. In the MongoDB configuration

   ```
   vim ~/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf
   ```

   add or set

   ```
   nojournal = true
   ```

Note: `~` automatically resolves to `/var/lib/openshift/<YOUR_OPENSHIFT_ID>`

3. Delete previous journal data

   ```
   rm ~/mongodb/data/journal/*
   ```

Then exit from SSH, and

4. restart MongoDB

   ```
   rhc cartridge-restart mongodb-2.4 -a $app
   ```

This of course, comes at the cost of not journaling, which is helpful for [recovering the data in case of corruption or unclean shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/). But if you're just testing things out and running out of space then disabling journaling can be very helpful as it takes a lot of space.

Comment: Great answer! Safe my day :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're hitting the disk quota that's either because you hit the size or inode limit.

To fix the size  you can clean up tmp folders, app logs, git repos etc. You can use:

```
rhc app-tidy -a <appname>
```

To check if you're hitting the inode limit use `quota` command:

```
quota -s
```

To fix the quota issue, you will need to keep number of files to a minimum.

If that doesn't help and you can try to shutdown the MongoDB and delete the contents of `mongodb` folder (i.e. use helmy's advice).

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB [preallocates data files](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database) and [may preallocate journal files](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/).

If your database is empty and/or you don't care about the data, try stopping mongod and then blowing away your data directory. Then verify/set the following mongod options:

```
smallfiles=true
noprealloc=true
```

Comment: sure, I can delete folder, but not sure how and where to specify this mongod options on remote server? any hints about that? right now, mongod is started by SailsJS framework, so I guess that I should somehow configure it on starting it.

Comment: Go to the OpenShift console for your application, there is a remote access link to the right. You will probably have to setup your ssh keys if you have not done that already. There is a link there for the SSH help page. After you're able to ssh into your OpenShift instance, you should be able to just edit /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: Actually do a ps auxwww | grep mongo to see what config file is being used. It may be using /var/lib/openshift/<YOUR_OPENSHIFT_ID>/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf. But it's probably already using smallfiles and noprealloc.

Comment: Ok, when I run  ps auxwww | grep mongo, here's what I got: http://paste.ofcode.org/K62ETfbYCmipbmdUnpnHft. Regarding etc/mongod/conf, I can't edit it, permission denied :/

Comment: PS: command to restart mongod on openshift `rhc cartridge-restart mongodb-2.4 -a <app-name>`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Login into your mongodb and run:

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

See more at: [MongoDB - file size is huge and growing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263729/mongodb-file-size-is-huge-and-growing)