# What is the initial size of MongoDB OpenShift cartridge?

Tags: mongodb, openshift-cartridge

On my OpenShift server console I executed:

`du -hs * | sort -h`

and got:

`60K    cron
128K    nodejs
11M redis
12M git
176M    app-deployments
180M    app-root
481M    mongodb`

I don't use mongo in the web app. Does it mean that 481M is the initial MongoDB cartridge size ?

Answer (score 0):

My initial mongodb directory size is the same, on a newly created Nodejs app with the MongoDB 2.4 cartrdige. Most of that space is used by the `~/mongodb/data/journal/` directory.

You can [disable journaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26340351/5400813) and delete the pre-allocated journal files, to save some space, if needed.